# Call function many times without duplicate it (with %>%)

Tags: r, pipe, apply, purrr, magrittr

Let's assume that we have 3 functions with this minimal functionality:

```
func1 <- function (x) {
  x + 1
}

func2 <- function (x, plus = T) {
  if (plus == TRUE) {
    x + 2
  } else {
    x - 5 
  }
}

func3 <- function (x) {
  x + 3
}
```

I would like to nest this function to each other like this with the pipe (%>%) operator:

```
library(magrittr)

func1(0) %>% func2(plus = T) %>% func2(plus = F) %>% func3
# result: 1
```

Which is the equivalent version of it:

```
func3(func2(func2(func1(0), plus = T), plus = F))
# result: 1
```

I try to find a method which doesn't require to duplacate the func2() function (because I have to run it many times and also I would like to change the number of function calls and the parameter dinamically). Currently I am not a big expert of apply functions or map package but I guess at least one of it can do this job.

It is of course just a dummy example, my real code is much more complicated, I just try to simplify my problem to find a solution.

I have to use the pipe operator so I only interested in that solutions which also work with pipes.

Comment: But you are calling the `func2` function with different parameters each time. So it's basically two different functions. How would you want to prevent its "duplication"? You can write your own helper functions to call functions multiple times, but it's a bit unclear exactly what you goal is here. Maybe you can show some pseduocode that shows that you would hope this would look like?

Comment: I want to determine the possible (1) outcomes and the order of the paramters and the number of function calls (2) like this in the beginning of the process: `outcomes <- c(T,F,F,F), nbr_of_runs <- 4` I need a solution which can generates the output according to this informations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function that takes the initial `x` and the outcomes to feed to `func2` and loops through those outcomes:

```
func2_iterate = function(x, outcomes){
  for (i in 1:length(outcomes)){
    x = func2(x, outcomes[i])
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Then run (with `func1`, `func2`, `func3` as above):

```
func1(0) %>% func2_iterate(c(T, F)) %>% func3
#result: 1
```

I'd also like to point out that in this particular case the output of `func2_iterate` is just its input, plus `2` times the number of `T` in `outcomes`, minus `5` times the number of `F` in `outcomes`.  But I assume you actually have functions that do something more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `partial` / `compose` / `invoke` combo :

```
library(tidyverse)
f2b <- invoke(compose, map(c(F,T), ~substitute(partial(func2, plus =.), lst(.))))

func1(0) %>% f2b %>% func3
# [1] 1
```